# Call postMessage on the window that created the current window.

Tags: javascript

I am creating a pop-up window using `var handle = window.open(url, name, options)`. This window contains many links that allow a user to navigate. After the user is done navigating, they can click a button to signal that they are done. When the user clicks this button, I would like to notify the original window that the user is done via `postMessage`. The issue I have is that I do not know how to get a handle to the original window. I tried `window.parent` but that doesn't work. How can I get a handle to the original window from the created window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the original window with "window.opener": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener.